# shuttlecloud "load method" request error

Tags: perl, api, http

I want use [shuttlecloud](https://shuttlecloud.com/) for import contacts from services. When i try make request like described here, i receive response

> {"error": {"msg": "Missing parameter: timestamp", "id": "400"}}

Here me code:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $url = 'https://demo.api.shuttlecloud.com/beta/load';
my $appid = 'some_app_id';
my $ts = int(time);
my $secret = 'some_secret';
my $sig = sha256_hex("{".$appid.":".$secret.":".$ts."}");
my $data = '{
    "userid": {
        "email": "admin@gypost.com"
    }
}';
my $json = decode_json($data);
$url = $url."?appid=".$appid."&ts=".$ts."&sig=".$sig.;
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $url);
$req->content($json);

my $resp = $ua->request($req);
my $res = $resp->decoded_content;
print "Resp $res\n";
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://shuttlecloud.com/api-requests#URLSecurityParameters), the security parameters `appid`, `ts`, and `sig` belong in the URL, not in HTTP headers. See the examples on the [common usage scenarios page](https://shuttlecloud.com/api-common-uses).

Comment: For starters - you're using JSON without `use JSON;`. But I think the clue is in the error message: "Missing parameter: timestamp

Comment: I change code, but now receive `Resp Not a SCALAR reference`. When i use curl for POST with created url - result is similar: `{"error": {"msg": "Missing parameter: timestamp", "id": "400"}}`

Comment: Can you paste the url you're using with curl?

Comment: when i POST created url (with parameters) its work, but when i try use parameters in `HTTP::Request` object - fail.